# How do I create different button for each item in an array / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, button, innerhtml

Here's my code:

```
var never = [1,2,3,4,7];

function please () {
  for (var i = 0; i < never.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("more").innerHTML = "<button>" + never[i] + "</button>";
  }
}
```

I have a button in my HTML that invokes this function but it only creates a button for the last item (7). How can I create a different button for each one of the items in the array? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are resetting the innerHTML after each iteration. You need to add + like this document.getElementById("more").innerHTML += "<button>" + never[i] + "</button>";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By *appending* to `innerHTML` instead of *assigning*, like

```js
var never = [1,2,3,4,7];

function please () {
  for (var i = 0; i < never.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("more").innerHTML += "<button>" + never[i] + "</button>";
  }
}

please();
```

```html
<div id="more">
</div>
```

Comment: Typo answer, lovely!

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to append created buttons in container.Each by each

```
var never = [1,2,3,4,7];

function please () {
  var more=document.getElementById("more");
  for (var i = 0; i < never.length; i++) {
    var butt=document.createElement("button");
    butt.innerHTML=never[i];
    more.appendChild(butt);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the most reasonable answer, the other ones are just waste of time.

Comment: Add a little more of info, please.   Doc for example.